# PHP form not sending to email address

Tags: php, forms, email

My PHP form used to send me an email successfully, however, now it displays the echo text as it should on submission of the form, but I don't seem to ever receive the email that I should from it?

PHP code:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Main Stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Alternative Stylesheet" href="/alternate%20stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<?php
// pull out the values from the request stream sent by the form
// and store those values into memory variables

$email   = $_REQUEST['email'];
$webmail   = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$firstName    = $_REQUEST['Firstname'];
$lastName  = $_REQUEST['Lastname'];
$sex     = $_REQUEST['sex'];
$to = 'myemailaddress';
$comment   =$_REQUEST['comment'];
$subject   =$_REQUEST['subject'];

// New code added for email validation
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("Email is not valid");
  exit();
}

$header    = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"';
$header   .= ' "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
$htmlhead  = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">';
$htmlhead .= '<head><title>Feedback Recieved</title>';
$htmlhead .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>';
$htmlbody  = '<body>';

// use the variables that store the information sent from the form.
 mail($to, $subject,"You have received the following feedback:". $comment, "from " . $firstName . " " . $lastName, "From: $email");
$htmlbody .= "<center><h1>Thank You</h1>";
$htmlbody .= "<p><b>" . $firstName . " " .  $lastName ;
$htmlbody .= "</b>, we've recieved an email from your email address: <b>" . $email . "</b>, and will respond as soon as possible!</p></center>";
$htmlbody .= "</body></html>";

// use echo to write all the information out back to the browser
echo $header . $htmlhead . $htmlbody ;
echo '<center>To return, click <a href="/is0502/index.html">here</a>.</center>';
?>
```

My form page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Main Stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Alternative Stylesheet" href="alternate%20stylesheet.css" />
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="siteWrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Parks</a>   <!-- Due to this being a drop-down nav link, the top link is active, but does not actually send the user to a different page, etc. -->
                    <!-- Code below: creates a new layer onto the lists -->
                    <ul>
                        <!-- Code below: makes a dropdown menu for the above menu item -->
                        <li><a href="disneyland.html">Disney Land</a>
                        <li><a href="universal.html">Universal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="buschgardens.html">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                        <!-- Code below: reverts the following contents of the list to a higher tier -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Restaurants</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="logans.html">Logans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="outback.html">Outback</a>
                        <li><a href="perkins.html">Perkins</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="statistics.html">Statistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="private/research_paper.html" target="_blank">Research Paper</a></li> <!-- The report page in the website opens in a new tab, enabling the user to return back to the website easily -->
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <div class="imageBanner" title="Beach I visited in Tampa">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
    </div>

<article>
<p>
I hope that you have found my personal experiences and recommendations helpful on this website, and if you have any questions, please do ask away in the form provided bellow.
</p>


    <form action="Scripts/studentinfo.php" method="get" id="studentinfo" onsubmit="return checkform()">

    <fieldset>
        <legend> Get in Contact </legend>
        <label>
        Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" value="your email address" />
        </label>
        <label>
        What department would you like to contact?
        <select name="subject">
           <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
           <option value="Website Issue">Website Issue</option>
           <option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
        </select>
        </label>
    <br/>
        <label>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="Firstname" value="Billy" />
        </label>
        <label>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Pickin" />
        </label>
        Gender
           <br/>
            <label>
            Male: 
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked" />
            </label>   
            <label>
            Female:
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
            </label>
            <label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="15" name="comment" value="please tell us what you think"> </textarea>
            </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </fieldset>

    </form>




</article>
<footer>
    &copy; Billy Pickin 2015. Disclaimer: all expressions on this site are strictly 
    personal opinions and preferences and may not actually reflect the locations, businesses, etc.
    factually.
</footer>
            <div id="bottomBarLeft">
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" target="_blank">
        <img src="/is0502/Photos/cssButton.png" alt="CSS Validation"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBarRight">
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" target="_blank">
        <img src="/is0502/Photos/html5button.png" alt="HTML5 validation"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: any specific reason you're using a GET method?

Comment: I have been told I have to, don't ask me why -_-

Comment: well you've some JS happening here `onsubmit="return checkform()` and no idea if it's related or not. Check for errors and look at your console. Accessed on a hosted server or local? 2 different animals here and if local, how? `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `file:///file.php`? Again... 2 different animals. Then do `if(mail(...)){ echo "Mail sent"; } else { echo "Something went terribly wrong"; }`

Comment: This is all on a hosted server. I'm such a noob at this stuff

Comment: I believe that I don't actually have to use the GET method, so following this, do you have any help for me please?